# Karate API Automation Tooling : Assert SOAP Response

Tags: automation, karate

SOAP responses are currently asserted from expected file.

Is there any way i exclude some fields which are dynamic ?

```
* def soap_response = read("expected.xml")
* match response == soap_response
```

assertion failed: path /soap:header /soap:time

Answer (score 0):

Yes just use `#ignore`:

```
<foo>#ignore</foo>
```

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#ignore-or-validate